# Getting bytes[] image from Database as IFormFile

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, http, dapper

I am making an API that can upload to and retrieve images from the database. The first part is done - the image gets stored in an `IFormFile` variable and gets passed to the database as `bytes[]`.

**Image** model:

```
public class Image
{
    public int recipeId { get; set; }
    public string format { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public IFormFile image { get; set; }
}
```

So this is how I am currently trying to write the GET method. My idea is to get the bytes from the database and convert them into a File that can afterward be visible on a web page.

```
 [Route("v1/recipe/image/{recipeId}")]
 [HttpGet()]
 public IActionResult GetImage(int recipeId)
 {
     byte[] data;
     try
     {
         using (var con = _connFactory())
         {
             data = con.Query("SELECT Image FROM RecipeImage WHERE RecipeId = @recipeId", new { recipeId }).FirstOrDefault();
         }

         return File(new MemoryStream(data), "image/jpeg", "SomeName.jpg");
     }
     catch (Exception exc)
     {
         return BadRequest();
     }
 }
```

`exc` looks like:

> {"Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'byte[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"}

I don't know whether this code is supposed to be correct or not but `data` is always null. I also tried the SQL statement (`SELECT Image FROM RecipeImage WHERE RecipeId = '140'`) in SSMS and it's bringing out the correct output:

[image: 1]]

Is there any other way in which I could achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: Yes. `Unable to cast object of type 'DapperRow' to type 'System.Byte[]` is what I am getting.

Comment: I already checked that one out, but couldn't figure out how to make it work on my part...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not telling `Dapper` what type to expect.

This should do it:

```
using (var con = _connFactory())
{
    data = con.Query<byte[]>("SELECT Image FROM RecipeImage WHERE RecipeId = @recipeId", new { recipeId }).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Personally I would prefer:

```cs
using (var con = _connFactory())
{
    data = con.QuerySingle<byte[]>("SELECT Image FROM RecipeImage WHERE RecipeId = @recipeId", new { recipeId });
}
```

which will throw an exception if more or less than one image is found.